# Do we need to delete a reference to a non new object?

Tags: c++, reference

```
classA objA (0, NULL);
classA & objB (objA);
```

Assuming the above to be global, can it result in a memory leak? Reasons?

Actually through Valgrind, I am getting an error:

`5 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable`
`...`
`global constructors keyed to classA`

What does that indicate?

**UPDATE:**

The exact errors are here.

```
at 0x4C2659D: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6653==    by 0x4EA7BB7: newterminal (in /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==6653==    by 0x4EA7D4E: Rf_InitConnections (in /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==6653==    by 0x4F420DD: setup_Rmainloop (in /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==6653==    by 0x4FEC76A: Rf_initEmbeddedR (in /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so)
==6653==    by 0x5C3A8DB: RInside::initialize(int, char const* const*, bool) (in /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.so)
==6653==    by 0x5C3AF60: RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool) (in /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.so)
==6653==    by 0x40D105: global constructors keyed to R
```

Comment: [Valgrind faq](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost) says the `still reachable` is not a major issue.

Comment: @KarthikT HUH! issue is a issue, major or minor doesn't matter. If valgind is saying somthing, there must be some reason behind it.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: That is very strange. Are you certain of it? As far as I remember, even completely empty types have at least the size of `1`.

Comment: @bitmask I'll print it again and confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you never called `new` so you dont have to call `delete`.

You should call `delete` only for dynamically allocated objects. Your object is not dynamically allocated, So you don't need to. If you do so it will result in Undefined Behavior.

Ofcourse, It is obvious and rather natural to assume that you do not have a `class A` constructor which leaks memory or causes undefined behavior.

---

Also, note that what is considered as memory leak is open for interpretation.

In your case the object in question is global and it is guaranteed to live throughout the lifetime of your program.  Even if this object leaks memory it is a not important at all.
This object is scheduled to be alive till the end of your program and even if it leaked memory, the duration of memory leak is destruction of this global object to the last statement in your program, after which the leaked memory will be reclaimed by the OS once your program ends.

So, practically it does not matter whether this object leaks, ofcourse valgrind would report it as a leak but it leaks when it doesn't matter to your program.

The kinds of leaks you should be worried about are ***recurring leaks***, functions or constructs which will leak memory repeatedly over the lifetime of the program. This is at best a ***finite leak*** scenario and it does not matter.

Comment: Any *meaningful* clarification on the downvote is appreciated.

Comment: Actually classA is a predefined class (by someone else). All I have done is calling its object and some functions. I didn't downvote.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Given that you do not have access to the source code and theres no documentation that says *"Hey the class i wrote is messy"* You can safely assume that the code does not cause any memory leak.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: *Still reachable* does not necessarily mean a memory leak. If I remember correctly the valgrind faq page explains it in detail.Please check that.

Comment: Ok, I'll check the FAQ. But what does the remaining error indicate?

Comment: FAQ syas: *""still reachable" means your program is probably ok -- ***it didn't free some memory it could have***. "* http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I saw the update and my answer is still the same, You do not need to call `delete`. This is not something which you should be bothered about.

Answer (score 2):

The object itself is not leaked because it is not dynamically allocated.

**But** the above could result in a memory leak for something like:

```
class classA
{
   classA() { new int[42]; }
};
```

This can be fixed though by providing a destructor or using RAII.

Comment: The implementation of classA is not known.

Comment: Even without a destructor, the memory "leaks" after main is done and thus is about to be released by the operating system anyway.

Comment: @bitmask what do you mean "even without a destructor". Without one, the memory leak is clear.

Comment: In my opinion this caveat is very orthogonal to the question, It has nothing to do (specifically) with references to a stack object.

Comment: You can add memory leak everywhere. But how is this related to the question?

Comment: @KarthikT it's not. The question is "can it result in a memory leak?" And the answer is - yes, it can.

Comment: @harper that's the question - "can it result in a memory leak?"

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I read the question "can the omitting of the delete causing a memory leak". Since the delete is prohibited the clear answer is NO and not some mystic other possibilities to leak. Als has stated clearly, never call delete for a reference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: My point was that even though your example is technically leaking memory, the memory leak (as opposed to the possible side effects from the dtor) is in no case relevant as the leak is neither accumulative nor long-lived. Theoreticall there is a leak, yes. Practically there is none as `objA` is global.

Comment: @harper 1. I don't see where delete is prohibited. 2. I tend to think about side-effects of the code & multiple possibilites changes to code & the code itself can have. You do not. That's ok. But don't call this "mystic".

Comment: @AnishaKaul is that the only object of that type you have in the code? If yes, and that's the only place were Valgrind reports a leak, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Since the reference objB is initialized with a non-heap object objB you shouldn't call delete neither for objA nor for objB, should you? You see.

Comment: @harper of course not. But that's not enough to answer "NO", because you don't know what the constructor does, right?

Comment: Luchain, I have added the exact messages now. Please see.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You really want to pass the stack memory to the heap? The classA destructor is responsible to clean up everything. And it *is* called with this==&objA when the objA left the scope. Taking a reference doesn't call a constructor and you have not to call any delete. BTW: You even don't have any pointer.